# Codeigniter upload files at root directory outside of the installation folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

This type of question has been asked here before, but no solution is working in this case. I have a website admin panel developed in `CI` and my directory looks like this.

```
uploads
    /stores
    /products
admin
    /application
    /system
    /assets
```

Now, I have to upload files in the subfolders of uploads that are residing in the root via a controller.

I have looked around other solutions and I have tried followings:

```
$upload_path = './uploads/stores/';
```

Above code is working when I keep uploads folder inside the admin folder. But I need to keep the uploads folder outside the admin.

I looked at the path `CI` uses and based on this, here is another method I tried

```
$upload_path = '../../uploads/stores/';
```

and also,

```
$upload_path = '/home/domain/public_html/uploads/stores/';
```

But this gives me following error.

> The path to the image is not correct.

I'm completely lost here. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried with it $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/stores/' ??
if it's not working then check it using file_exist function for the same location.

Comment: I already tried this, but did not work

Comment: print_r($_FILES); is returning all the data of files ? can you update your question with code because there may be a problem while do_upload().

Comment: yes, i'm getting files, but the problem is just in the upload path.

Comment: also array of your file which is returning in print_r($_FILES).

Comment: If you are working on live then check folder permission.

Comment: Sometimes hosting services don't allow anything from apache to be put outside the web root, perhaps have a look if you might be able to solve it to upload files over FTP with codeigniter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign following path when you upload your images.

```
    $uploadpath = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folderame';
```

The document root directly under which the current script is executing,as define in the server configuration file.

Comment: Edition in code: `$uploadpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folderame';`

Comment: for more detail visit this which surely user has directly taken the answer [Link](http://howcanfix.com/32558/codeigniter-upload-files-at-root-directory-outside-of-the-installation-folder)

Comment: @ankitsuthar This link has taken the question and answer from this page.

Answer (score 1):

> Use APPPATH and FCPATH to make the correct structure:

1. FCPATH : path to folder containing you project
2. APPPATH : path to application folder

   ```
   echo  FCPATH .'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stores';
   ```

Comment: This code is returning the same path I have tried before and that is giving me error.

Comment: /home/domain/public_html/uploads/stores

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->input->post('img_status') == 3){//here 3 is indicating that new image is selected
    if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $name_array = '';
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp'; 
        $config['max_size'] = '1000'; 
        $config['max_width'] = '1280'; 
        $config['max_height'] = '1280'; 
        $this->load->library('upload'); 
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            $this->upload->display_errors(); 
        else { 
            $fInfo = $this->upload->data(); //uploading
            $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');//fetching path
            $config1 = array(
                  'source_image' => $fInfo['full_path'], //get original image
                  'new_image' => $this->gallery_path.'/thumb', //save as new image //need to create thumbs first
                  'maintain_ratio' => true,
                  'width' => 250,
                  'height' => 250

                );
            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1); //load library
            $this->image_lib->resize(); //generating thumb
            $imagename=$fInfo['file_name'];// we will get image name here
            $dataInsert['image'] = $imagename;
        }   
    }
}
else if($this->input->post('img_status') == 2){
    $dataInsert['image'] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: With only code, I have no ideas how and if this post answers the question. Please see [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Directory handling is very easy for each directoy you want to move up ../ so

Try this, just keep adding ../ until you get where you want to go.
Code:
$dir = "../../gallery/safe/";